# Can we call a CMS like Drupal Machine Learning?

Tags: machine-learning

Drupal process a page and created run time PHP files, Twig files, sometimes CSS/JS as well, from the fragments we have already created based on it's logic.

Since machine learning does some similar thing to act on the data and use own logic to produce result, can we can CMS to be bit of Machine Learning capabilities?

Answer (score 1):

No: a CMS, like many other software tools, processes data. But this process is predefined, it's not "learnt" from the data.

Machine Learning is supposed to involve at least one step where the system "learns" from the data, i.e. uses some algorithmic process to determine the characteristics (patterns) inside the data. In supervised learning there is a specific training stage where the model "learns", which is followed by a testing stage where the model is applied to some new data. In unsupervised learning, learning and applying happen in a single stage: the model discovers the patterns and directly produces an output based on these pattern.

Comment: When we want to provide new data, like using aggregator which picks up content from another website displays data. So it is kind of being provided data and learning itself although not fitting the definition very much.

Comment: @VishalKumarSahu in general an aggregator takes content in the order that it's published from a predefined list of website, so there's no learning anywhere: the content is not analyzed in any way by the system.